# RsaCryptoProvider C# export public key in DER format

Tags: c#, rsa

Without using Bouncy Castle - using just C# .NET I need to generate a public/private key pair and send the public key to a service by BASE64 Encoding the key in DER format.

Can anyone help with the export in DER format? I can create the keypair easily enough but the DER format has me stumped.

Comment: Why do you not want to use Bouncy Castle?

Comment: So, you have the public key already generated, and need to convert it to DER format? What format is it currently, PEM?

Comment: .NET doesn't provide a DER or ASN.1 encoder in the BCL so you have two options: start reading reference docs (http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) and write your own, or use a 3p library such as Bouncy Castle or Open SSL etc.

Comment: By the way, this answer shows the format of an ASN.1 public key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281102/reading-a-asn-1-der-encoded-rsa-public-key/5266564#5266564  you would be generating this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039170/6535399 may help.  If you don't have a certificate you can perhaps use https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099047/6535399 to figure out how to build the RSAPublicKey value for WrapAsBitString

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [OpenSSL](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO26630.html)

> If your server/device requires a different certificate format other
>   than Base64 encoded X.509, a third party tool such as OpenSSL can be
>   used to convert the certificates into the appropriate format.

[GitHub - OpenSSl.NET](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net)